# Transfer app without developer enrollment?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I have two apple ID's. I created a new one for my new company and bought enrollment for it. The old account has three apps that are no longer available on the store, since the enrollment ran out of time on the first account.

I have bought memebership for the new account.
It seems like I can't transfer any applications from the old account to the new account before the old account has enrolled again. The option 'Transfer this app' simply does not show up anymore. The apps are stuck at the status 'Pending Contract'.

What can I do to transfer the apps from the old account from the new one?
Will I have to pay for a membership for the old account too?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only renewing your account.

But ask directly to Apple in this link: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

I needed to change my username in App Store and was attended by this channel. If possible they will make the transfer requesting some documents proving that the accounts are yours.